# Mysql Join AND SUM

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Please look to this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2RB2.jpg

i want to get

1. sum of money in table come
2. sum of money in table leave
3. inner join  emp using id

Thats my query

```
SELECT uid,SUM(money) FROM come 
INNER JOIN emp ON(come.uid = emp.id) 
WHERE emp.statue=1 
GROUP BY come.uid 
UNION 
SELECT uid,SUM(money) FROM `leave` 
INNER JOIN emp ON ( leave.uid = emp.id ) 
GROUP BY leave.uid
```

and the result was this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZtO3.jpg

Comment: I would use a UNION ALL rather than UNION (should be quicker as it does not have to sort)

Comment: @Kevin, UNION doesn't sort, it removes duplicate rows (so UNION ALL should be faster, but for a different reason ^_^)

Comment: @jswolf19 I'll concede it may not, but sometimes, does: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-sort-union.html I guess the only way to be sure is the check your execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it (not tested, so let me know if it blows up):

```
SELECT emp.id, IF(emp.statue=1, c.sumCome, 0) AS sumCome, l.sumLeave
FROM emp
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, SUM(money) AS sumCome
                FROM come
                GROUP BY uid
               ) c ON emp.id = c.uid
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT uid, SUM(money) AS sumLeave
                FROM leave
                GROUP BY uid
               ) l ON emp.id = l.uid
```

I don't know which'll be faster compared to Kevin's. You might want to `explain` them both and see.

Comment: You Query is perfect , can you tell me information about this query    explain it :)

Comment: @samarlover, where do I need to start explaining? Do you know what a `join` is? A `left join`? a subquery? do you understand the `if` function?

Answer (score 0):

here we go:

```
SELECT q1.uid,SUM(q1.l),SUM(q1.c) FROM
(
SELECT uid,0 as l,SUM(money) as c FROM come 
INNER JOIN emp ON (come.uid = emp.id) 
WHERE emp.statue=1 GROUP BY come.uid 
UNION ALL 
SELECT uid,SUM(money) as l,0 as c FROM leave
INNER JOIN emp ON ( leave.uid = emp.id ) GROUP BY leave.uid 
) q1
GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: Thank you for answer  the result is                                       #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   select uid,sum(ComeTot),sum(LeaveTot)
   from
  (

    SELECT uid,SUM(money) as ComeTot ,0 as LeaveTot
    FROM come 
    INNER JOIN emp ON(come.uid = emp.id) WHERE emp.statue=1 
    GROUP BY come.uid 
    UNION 
    SELECT uid,0 ,SUM(money) FROM leave
    INNER JOIN emp ON ( leave.uid = emp.id ) 
    GROUP BY leave.uid
  ) xx

GROUP BY xx.uid
```

I don't have mySQL installed on this PC, but this should get you close.   Depending on the result of the above, you might need to wrap the entire query above in another group by...

Comment: your query is very good but didn't get the answer but it get me   look to this pic `http://i.stack.imgur.com/adfVb.jpg`

Comment: I adapted the query which should get you want you need, but not tested since I don't have mySQL installed