# Cannot retrieve value of extra query per record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Im working on a table where data from users will be picked from database.

The problem is that im not being able to put two statements on my while condition because im getting data from different tables and rows.

**@CODE**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("select * FROM users");

$space_used = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(fileSize) FROM file WHERE file.userId=users.id AND file.statusId=1");

$total_files = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM file WHERE file.userId=users.id AND file.statusId=1");

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' id='sample_editable_1'>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Type</th>                                   
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Last Login</th>
    <th>Last IP</th>
    <th>space_used</th>
    <th>total_files</th>
    <th>status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lastlogindate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lastloginip'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $space_used['space_used'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $total_files['total_files'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What im getting is all the values of username, level, email, lastlogindate, lastloginip & status. The two that are not showing on my table are the ones of the second condition i want to implement: space_used and total_files.

What am i doing wrong? Im not an expert in php and the fact that i had a mix of tutorials and a script im chaning to get to this result had complicated a little bit.

Thanks

Comment: Note: the `mysql` library is deprecated and has been removed since PHP 5.5 - you're running an outdated version. when you or your host upgrades, your application will stop working.

Comment: You really need to read up on how to do SQL table joins, as this is what you need to be doing.  You can get all this data in one query.  You also should NOT be using `mysql_*` function, as they are deprecated.  So whatever tutorials you are following are really outdated.  You should investigated use of `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @ConnorPeet: Don't oversell it; ext/mysql is deprecated, but not yet removed AFAIK.  I'd be surprised if it's taken out before 5.7, if even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework your query, you can resume your 3 queries into a single query using `JOIN`:

```
  SELECT u.*, 
         SUM(f.fileSize) AS space_used, 
         COUNT(f.id) AS total_files
    FROM users u
    JOIN file f 
      ON f.userId = u.id AND f.statusId = 1
GROUP BY u.id
```

Then you can read it like this:

```
<?php
// your database info
$db_host = 'your MySQL server host';
$db_user = 'your username';
$db_pass = 'your password';
$db_name = 'your database name';
$con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if($con->connect_error)
{
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!$result = $con->query("SELECT u.*,
                                   SUM(f.fileSize) AS space_used, 
                                   COUNT(f.id) AS total_files
                              FROM users u
                              JOIN file f 
                                ON f.userId = u.id AND f.statusId = 1
                          GROUP BY u.id"))
{
    die('Select query error: ' . $con->error);
}
?>
<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' id='sample_editable_1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Type</th>                                   
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Last Login</th>
        <th>Last IP</th>
        <th>space_used</th>
        <th>total_files</th>
        <th>status</th>
    </tr>
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['level']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastlogindate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastloginip']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['space_used']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['total_files']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
$con->close();
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to aggregate per userId.

**Pull** these two query's into the while loop. Use the retrieved User's `id` to Make the aggregate query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $space_used = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(fileSize) FROM file WHERE file.userId={$row['id']} AND file.statusId=1");
    $total_files = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM file WHERE file.userId={$row['id']} AND file.statusId=1");
    ...
 }
```

**Combine** them into one query.

```
$agragateDataResponce = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(fileSize) as size,
                                            COUNT(id) as count 
                                       FROM file 
                                      WHERE file.userId={$row['id']} AND 
                                            file.statusId=1");
$agragateData = mysql_fetch_array($agragateDataResponce);
```

**Access** by `$agragateData['size']` and `$agragateData['count']`;

Then look up how to combine the remaining two SQL into one join :) . [SO Question on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107395/mysql-join-and-sum)

Answer (score 0):

First you query the database and save the results into variables.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * FROM users");
$space_used = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(fileSize) FROM file WHERE file.userId=users.id AND file.statusId=1");
$total_files = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM file WHERE file.userId=users.id AND file.statusId=1");
```

Then you iterate through the first of your results with

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Notice your call to `mysql_fetch_array`. You never call `mysql_fetch_array` on the other two results.

See the [PHP documentation on `mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for more details. Specifically, the return type is a *resource*.

> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.

However,

```
SELECT SUM(fileSize) FROM file WHERE file.userId=users.id AND file.statusId=1
```

is not even what you want. You check for `file.userId=users.id` but only read from the `file` table. You are missing the users source table.

Comment: "You never call mysql_fetch_array on the other two results." And how do i do that? thats kind of the answer im looking for. thanks

Comment: I have done this: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($space_used) && $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($total_files)) but didnt worked

Comment: I removed that code I put in for a moment because it’s invalid as you query for only one result for the second and third query. So you don’t want to iterate over the results but fetch the result only once for those.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$space_used = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(fileSize) 
                             FROM file 
                            WHERE file.userId=users.id AND 
                                  file.statusId=1");

$total_files = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) 
                              FROM file 
                             WHERE file.userId=users.id AND 
                                   file.statusId=1");
```

the above lines inside the `While` and verify with the `user.id`

I am new to stackoverflow so don't mine. I don't know how to make a code look like every one do